# Creating Backbone Marionette Carousel View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I want to know the better way create a Backbone Marionette Carousel View. Right now I have a collection view that renders all the views and I show/hide each view when the user clicks next and previous buttons. But is this the best way of doing? Is it better to just create one view and reuse it? or is there a better approach? I have fairly complex view in the carousel with Highcharts graphs and other data it is not a simple view with some text and pictures in it. and I can have lot of views in the carousel.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it as is, but if performance is too heavy - then when clicking next or moving to the next view, i would initialize the new view and when the "render" finishes i would show it, and destroy the previous. that way it is more performance efficient.